# What does it mean when it says "read" under an SMS in Messages?

Tags: messages

I have never seen the "read" tag before, however I have seen "delivered" and nothing. What does the "read" tag mean?

Answer (score 4):

Delivered means that it's gotten to its destination. Read means that the user has actually opened the text in the Messages app.

Comment: I also believe that you can only get the read tag for iMessages.

Comment: Also the receiver has to turn on the functionality for "read" status to be sent as a response.  It's the "Send Read Receipts" toggle under messages.

Comment: For Mac App Messages users on ML, the same configuration appears under Preferences -> Accounts -> (Select your iMessage acct) -> Send Read Receipts

Answer (score 0):

Read means the user that you sent the message to actually opened up the iMessage app. If it says delivered, they most likely didn't look at the message although it was sent through. You can change it though in Settings to make it that you don't send a read receipt when you read a message.

Comment: what about when the full message appears on the lock screen, or in any other notification?

Answer (score -1):

It means the person you sent the message to has read it.